# History of tropical mathematics

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, tropical-geometry, semirings

This is a follow-up to [this question about the origin of tropical mathematics.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437218/origin-of-tropical-mathematics)

Are there any articles, websites or books which deal with the history of tropical mathematics?

I have been trying to find out the major milestones in this field's development by crawling the bibliographies of articles on the subject and reading their prefaces, which has been neither fruitful nor efficient.

What I'm asking for is a more or less recent source which goes into the major advances that were made over the years in tropical mathematics, especially tropical algebra and to be really specific, the spectral properties of matrices over the tropical semiring.